# Adding a label to an Epilog line

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following code:

```
ListLinePlot[pWoKC1, PlotRange -> {{0, 63}, {0, 1}},Epilog -> Line[{{0,datapCWMWoKCp[[1]]}, {63, datapCWMWoKCp[[1]]}}], PlotLabel -> "Title", AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}]
```

which produces the figure shown below. Top cap it off, I wish to add a label to the black line, but I am having difficulty working out how to change my code to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use `Text` inside of `Epilog` in order to add labels to various things:

```
Plot[
 E^(-1/8 x) + 0.15, {x, 0, 63},
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"},
 PlotLabel -> "Title",
 PlotRange -> {{0, 63}, {0, 1}},
 Epilog ->
  {
   Line[{{0, 0.15}, {63, 0.15}}],
   Text[Style["Line Label", Black], {10, 0.18}]
 }]
```

Where I have `Black` inside of `Style` you can put various arguments like `FontFamily` and `FontSize` if you're interested in changing the style. If the default style is okay, then you don't really need the `Style` part and just `Text["Line Label", {10, 0.18}]` would do.

[image: Plot using epilog to add a label to a line.]